Autocorrelating output signal which sampled at rates higher than signalling rate
A bpsk signal(a$_{n}$) with d$_{min}$ = 1, passes through a pulse shaping filter p(t), the resultant pulse shaped signal ($\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_{n}p(t-nT_{s})$) passes through an AWGN channel which adds zero mean gaussian noise v(t) with variance $\sigma^{2}$, this resultant signal then passes through the matched filter p*(-t), let the resulting signal be y(t), i want to autocorrelate this signal in two cases, first case is when i am sampling the signal at rate $\frac{1}{T_{s}}$, and second case being when i am sampling it at rate $\frac{k}{T_{s}}$, where k is an integer greater than 1
So obviously in first case since the sampling is done at exactly the signalling rate, there is no isi and autocorr function becomes 0 for lags > 0, whereas in other case autocorr function is non zero for higher lags, and looks something like a sinc function as function of lag $\delta$ for the case when i use sinc pulse for pulse shaping. I need to prove that autocorrelation is non zero for second case and maybe get a closed function for the same.

please show your progress in your proof and where you are stuck exactly. What exactly is your question?

Let the output of the matched filter $h_{mf}(t) = p^{*}(-t)$ be $y(t) = \bar{y}(t) + v(t)$. $\bar{y}(t) = (s*h_{mf})(t)$ is the received signal where the transmitted signal $s(t)$ is given by $s(t) = \sum_{n}a_{n}p(t-nT_{s})$. $v(t) = (w*h_{mf})(t)$ is the received noise where $w(t)$ is the AWGN with variance $\sigma^{2}$.
When sampling at the symbol rate, there is no ISI. The noiseless matched filter output $\bar{y}(t)$ can be expressed as:
$$
\bar{y}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(t^{\prime} - nT_s) p^{*}(t^{\prime} - t)dt^{\prime}
$$
Since the pulse shaping filter $p(t)$ is typically designed such that $p(t) * p^*(-t) = \delta(t)$ at $t = nT_s$, we have: $\bar{y}(nT_s) = a_n$. The autocorrelation function $R_{\bar{y}}(\tau)$ of $\bar{y}(t)$ sampled at $t = nT_s$ is:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\{\bar{y}(nT_s) \bar{y}^{*}(mT_s + \tau)\}
$$
For $\tau = 0$:
$$
\begin{align}
R_{\bar{y}}(0) & = \mathbb{E}\{\bar{y}(nT_s) \bar{y}^{*}(nT_s)\} \\
& = \mathbb{E}\{(a_n)(a_n)^{*}\} \\
& = \mathbb{E}\{|a_n|^2] \\
& = 1
\end{align}
$$
For $\tau \neq 0$:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}(\tau) = \mathbb{E}\{\bar{y}(nT_s) \bar{y}^{*}(mT_s + \tau)\} = 0
$$
because $\mathbb{E}\{a_n a_m^{*}\} = 0$ for $n \neq m$.
Thus, the autocorrelation function $R_{\bar{y}}(\tau)$ is:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}(\tau) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \tau = 0 \\
0 & \text{if } \tau \neq 0
\end{cases} 
$$
When sampling at a rate higher than the symbol rate, ISI is introduced because symbols are not orthogonal at these sample points. The received signal sampled at $t = m \frac{T_s}{k}$ (with $m$ being an integer) is:
$$
\bar{y}\left(m \frac{T_s}{k}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(t^{\prime} - nT_s) p^{*}\left(t^{\prime} - m \frac{T_s}{k}\right)dt^{\prime}
$$
To compute the autocorrelation $R_{\bar{y}}(\tau)$, consider $\tau = l \frac{T_s}{k}$:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}\left(l \frac{T_s}{k}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left\{\bar{y}\left(m \frac{T_s}{k}\right) \bar{y}^{*}\left((m + l) \frac{T_s}{k}\right)\right\} 
$$
Assuming $p(t)$ is a sinc pulse:
$$
p(t) = \textrm{sinc}\left(\frac{t}{T_s}\right)
$$
The convolution of two sinc pulses results in another sinc function:
$$
\left(p(t) * p^{*}(-t)\right)(\tau)\biggr\rvert_{\tau = \frac{\tau}{T_s}} = \textrm{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau}{T_s}\right)
$$
Thus, the autocorrelation function for the sampled signal is:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}\left(l \frac{T_s}{k}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \mathbb{E}\left\{a_n a_n^*\right\} \textrm{sinc}\left(\frac{l}{k}\right)
\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
$$
Since $\mathbb{E}\{|a_n|^2\} = 1$:
$$
R_{\bar{y}}\left(l \frac{T_s}{k}\right) = \text{sinc}\left(\frac{l}{k}\right)
\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
$$
If $p(t)$ is a root raised cosine (RRC) pulse, then the autocorrelation $p(t)*p^{*}(-t)$ results in a raised cosine (RC) pulse that can be expressed as
$$
\left(p(t)*p^{*}(-t)\right)(\tau) = \textrm{rc}(\tau)
$$. In \eqref{eq:1} & \eqref{eq:2}, replace $\textrm{sinc}$ with $\textrm{rc}$.
For the noise at the output of the matched filter, the autocorrelation is given by
$$
\begin{align}
R_{v}(\tau) & = \mathbb{E}\{v(t+\tau)v^{*}(t)\} \\
& = \mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}w(t+\tau-\alpha)h_{mf}(\alpha)d\alpha\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}w^{*}(t-\beta)h_{mf}^{*}(\beta)d\beta\right)\right\} \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\{w(t+\tau-\alpha)w^{*}(t-\beta)\}}_{\sigma^{2}\delta(\tau-\alpha+\beta)}h_{mf}(\alpha)h_{mf}^{*}(\beta)d\alpha d\beta \\
& = \sigma^{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_{mf}(\alpha)h_{mf}^{*}(\alpha-\tau)d\alpha \stackrel{h_{mf}(t) = p^{*}(-t)}{=} \sigma^{2}(p(t)*p^{*}(-t))(\tau)
\end{align}
$$
Since data symbols $a_{n}$ and noise $w(t)$ are independent (thus uncorrelated), then $R_{y}(\tau) = R_{\bar{y}}(\tau)+R_{v}(\tau)$.

Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive and clear proof

I had a doubt tho, the awgn noise v(t) will be added before matched filtering right?? so after it passes through the filter it won't be white noise anymore right?? or am i missing somethng, will that not affect correlation??

@DarkKnight_007, you are absolutely right. I overlooked that fact in my reply. Edited the answer to take into account your point.

Thank you so much brother
